# Add string array to request in Spring controller in order to forward to another service

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, web

I'm looking to cut out the JSP middleman here. I have a POST Spring endpoint that returns a string representing a view. This view is a JSP ("the middleman") that simply POSTs hidden HTML input elements on `$(document).ready()` to another system's URL. In order to remove this JSP, I will need to stuff the request parameters w/in the calling controller already mentioned (e.g., `request.setAttribute("var1", "val1")`).

**First question**: should I do this by returning a `"forward:" + URL`? A redirect does not seem to be an option because the outside-system's endpoint is expecting a POST (instead of a *get* in what would be the first post-redirect-get pattern of this flow).

**Second question**: There is a loop in the JSP that stuffs the same hidden input element multiple times:

```
<c:forEach var="elem" items="${requestScope.elements}">
    <input type="hidden" name="thing" value="<c:out value="${elem}"/>">         
</c:forEach>
```

How would I migrate this to the calling controller. Perhaps, something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/path_val", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    // below is the code in question
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<String> elements = (List<String>) request.getAttribute("elements");
    for (ListIterator<String> elemIter = elements.listIterator(); elemIter.hasNext();) {
        request.setAttribute("item[" + elemIter.nextIndex() + "]", elemIter.next());
    }
    return "forward:" + outsideURL;
}
```

Comment: Is it seems like, you are getting a HTML from first controller via ajax then you are sending the response HTML to another controller? And your are trying remove this middleman? Sorry for asking.

Comment: The Spring controller is just sending data to the JSP. The JSP, in turn, is synchronously POSTing hidden fields to another URL. I'm trying to remove the JSP and instead POST from the controller to the other URL.